# JQuery duplicate events when create element and set events to class

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

When I add an item using click event and exists another element with the same class the event is duplicated.

```js
$(".add-first").on("click", function() {
  var firstContainer='<div class="second-container"><button class="add-second">add second</button></div>';
  $(this).closest(".first-container").append(firstContainer);
  $(".add-second").on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest(".second-container").append("<br>example");
  });
});
$(".add-second").on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest(".second-container").append("<br>example");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first-container">
  <button class="add-first">add first</button>
  <div class="second-container"><button class="add-second">add second</button></div>
</div>
```

Then when I press one click in `add first` this duplicate event in each button `add second`, then when I press click on the second button it has some events, the issue is duplicated event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to implement [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) instead of binding an event event every time when you are creating a new button,

```
$(".add-first").on("click", function() {
  var firstContainer = '<div class="second-container"><button class="add-second">add second</button></div>';
  $(this).closest(".first-container").append(firstContainer);
});

$(".first-container").on("click", ".add-second", function() {
  $(this).closest(".second-container").append("<br>example");
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3aocq6mj/)